# Calling base-class members by expanding each parameter pack fails in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    void GoImpl() { cout << "A"; }
};

class B
{
public:
    void GoImpl() { cout << "B"; }
};

template <class... Mixins>
class Foo : public Mixins...
{
public:
    void Go()
    {
        int temp[] = { 0, (Mixins::GoImpl(), 0)... };
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<A, B> foo;
    foo.Go();  // ERROR: illegal call of non-static member function

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine in `GCC` or clang, but fails in `Visual Studio 2017` with:

> error C2352: 'A::GoImpl': illegal call of non-static member function

I haven't found any specific information on this.  Is this just a bug (or unimplemented feature) in the compiler, or there some voodoo I'm missing?  Can you suggest any workarounds?  I'm specifically attempting to call a base-class function on each base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, try

```
    int temp[] = { 0, (this->Mixins::GoImpl(), 0)... };
```

or

```
    int temp[] = { 0, (static_cast<Mixins*>(this)->GoImpl(), 0)... };
```

Comment: Yup, this works.  Any idea why Visual Studio requires an explicit this pointer?

Comment: @rezbot in general, when trying to call methods of a base whose type is dependent on a template parameter, `this` must be used.  Now this case may be an exception (I have not checked the standard), but I presumed this rule was why MSVC was getting confused here.